# Процесс приложения завершается после длительного времени в свернутом режиме

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно предотвратить завершение процесса приложения, когда приложение находится длительное время, в свернутом режиме?

Имеется класс:

```
public class ListActivity extends BaseActivity implements TaskListFragment.Callback

 { @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);        
        gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);
        if(!gpsTracker.canGetLocation()){
            gpsTracker.showSettingsAlert();
        }        
        startService(new Intent(this, PushBackgroundService.class)); 
        startService(serviceLocation);
    }
};
```

который при создании стартует 2 сервиса. Пока приложение открыто, все выполняется должным образом. Но как только, приложение сворачивается, то через некоторое время процесс завершается. Полагаю, что сперва происходит OnPause(), а далее OnStop(). Но никак не могу понять, как можно предотвратить завершения процесса, чтобы сохранить все действующие операции?

Comment: Никак. Создавайте правильно ForegroundService.

Comment: Времена, когда разрешалось поназапускать сервисов и "сожрать" всю батарею пользователю, давно прошли. Вот тут расписан алгоритм что и для каких задач сейчас надо выбирать: https://developer.android.com/guide/background

Answer (score 0):

Что бы приоритет сервиса был как у запущенного приложения надо создавать ForegroundService, все остальное не гарантирует работу сервиса в фоне, система может убить сервис в любой момент. Не забудьте добавить пермишены для ForegroundService.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Для сервисов в данный момент существуют некоторые проблемы в виде:

1. Ограничение трафика в бэке Data Saver
2. Списки оптимизации энергопотребления(причем на разных смартах списки разные, минимум мне известно 5)

Вообще есть несколько вариантов работы с пушами:

1. FCM hight priority push - если шлете не приват в тексте
2. [Запрос на отключение ограничения трафика](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager)
3. [Исключения из списка оптимизации](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33114063/how-do-i-properly-fire-action-request-ignore-battery-optimizations-intent)